# getting item's name when clicking a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick

Is there any way I can capture a name of an item clicked in a list view when using "onItemLongClickListiner" ? I know I can capture position etc but I need a name

Comment: what all does your row contain? textview, button..?

Comment: What do you mean by 'name'? If it is a textView you can get the text yes!

Comment: if its a textview `String s = listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()` in `onItemLongClickListiner`.

Comment: Item's name inside a list view

Comment: what is the item actually a text? coz listivew rows can have other views as well like buttons

Comment: @Frugo look at the answer by blackbelt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose that you `ListView` is filled up with String object:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 String name = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
}
```

[AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29) gets the data associated with the specified position in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lv.getItemAtPosition(position)` to get the text based on the index position

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
        long arg3) 
{
    String name = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
}
});
```

For more info

[getItemAtPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29)

Comment: you can use directly arg0 to get the item

Comment: @blackbelt using the item id?

Comment: the position. take a look the AdapterView doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29)

Comment: @blackbelt yup i have mentioned the position. "arg0" was just a copy paste error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //inflated row layout textview
            TextView tagText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_text);
            String tag = tagText.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Element Name " + tag + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It has worked for me.

```
listtview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l){
       String selected = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is"+selected,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```