# Get name of the rowItem in listView onClick

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to implement a simple `listView` with `onClick` functionality. On clicking the item in the `listView`, I want to show the name of the item in a `'toast` message, but I am unable to do that. I have used the method suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389231/getting-items-name-when-clicking-a-listview) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891026/get-clicked-item-from-listview) but couldn't get the desired result. I have added my code below :

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rowItem = new AppList();
        final ListView userInstalledApps = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.appListView);

        List<AppList> installedApps = getInstalledApps();
        CustomAppAdapter installedAppAdapter = new CustomAppAdapter(MainActivity.this, installedApps);
        userInstalledApps.setAdapter(installedAppAdapter);

        userInstalledApps.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                TextView appName = (TextView)adapterView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Clicked "+ adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

**CustomAppAdapter.java**

```
    public class CustomAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<AppList> listStorage;
    Context context;

    public CustomAppAdapter(Context context, List<AppList> listStorage) {
        layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.listStorage = listStorage;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listStorage.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder listViewHolder;
        if(convertView == null){
            listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_app_list, parent, false);

            listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name);
            listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
            convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
        }else{
            listViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
        listViewHolder.imageInListView.setImageDrawable(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{

        TextView textInListView;
        ImageView imageInListView;
    }
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the `listView` : [image: ListView]

On trying this method:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Clicked "+ adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Suppose I clicked on the 2nd item in the `listView` so I get a `toast` message as `Clicked 2`. But I want that it shows me `Clicked PhonePe`

Comment: In your `CustomAppAdapter.java` of the method `getItem(..)` you return the `position` instead of `return listStorage.get(position);`

Comment: @Vall0n, I didn't get you, where should I return the position and of what?

Comment: `@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
       return listStorage.get(position);
    }` in your `CustomAppAdapter.java` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rowItem = new AppList();
        final ListView userInstalledApps = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.appListView);

        List<AppList> installedApps = getInstalledApps();
        CustomAppAdapter installedAppAdapter = new CustomAppAdapter(MainActivity.this, installedApps);
        userInstalledApps.setAdapter(installedAppAdapter);

        userInstalledApps.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                TextView appName = (TextView)adapterView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Clicked "+ installedApps.get(i).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Try this.

Comment: Doesn't work, it shows `Clicked com.example.myapplication.AppList@49bc05cd`, and also I added `.toString()`, but still doesn't show the name of the `rowItem`  clicked

Comment: Oh. Try this. installedApps.get(i).getName()

Comment: Ya, sure. I will!!